# Selection of different input field for different user through dropdown input field's value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form to insert data into database.Three user for my system such as Exam controller,teacher and student.After the selection of their type they will get different input field that fulfil each purpose.
In the picture below,

[image]

> 1 as Student , 2 as Exam-Controller , 3 as Teacher is a dropdown input filed

Above this dropdown  all input field is similar for all user but below this, input field will be specified according to user need.
such as,

> i don't want to insert data of student id,session,department,hall field as teacher

> i don't want to insert data of student id,position,session,department,hall field as exam controller

here that html that call changeStatus function.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span><select id="status_user" onchange="changeStatus()"class="form-control input-md" name="u_type"           required="required">
        <option>1 as Student , 2 as Exam-Controller , 3 as Teacher</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                            
    </select>
</div><br>
```

Here's the javascript part of my code

```
function changeStatus() {
    var status = document.getElementById("status_user");

    if(status.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "none";//action performed to position input field
    }else if (status.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById("id1").style.display = "none"; //action performed to Student Id input field

        document.getElementById("dp").style.display = "none"; //action performed to Department input field
        document.getElementById("ss").style.display = "none"; //action performed to Session input field

        document.getElementById("hl").style.display = "none"; //action performed to Hall input field

        document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "none"; //action performed to position input field
    }else if (status.value == 3) {
        document.getElementById("id1").style.display = "none";
        
        

        document.getElementById("ss").style.display = "none";
        
        document.getElementById("hl").style.display = "none";
    
        document.getElementById("sm").style.display = "none";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("id1").style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById("dp").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("ss").style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById("hl").style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "block";
        
    }
}
```

Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: You said you want to insert values into a database but your code doesn't show any database. so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Database functionality is working but problem is in js portion.as example when i select 1, i get necessary field that actually picture that is given above. On the ohter hand when i select 2 i can't get exam controller field. Similarly it don't work for teacher by selecting 3. Important point is that i have put null value by deafult in DB to perform this task.